# Locating an element under div

Tags: css, class, selenium, xpath, element

```
 <div class="form-item">
   <label class="form-item-label">Mailing Account:</label>
   <div class="form-element">
     <div class="form-field-wrap>
       <input class="form-text x-form-field x-combo-noedit">
       </input>
```

I am trying to locate the element `<input class="form-text x-form-field x-combo-noedit">` comes under `<label class="form-item-label">Mailing Account:</label>`.

First element should be matched on text "Mailing Account:" and the second element on any of these classes "form-text x-form-field x-combo-noedit".

Can someone suggest a logic using using `xpath` or `cssSelector`please?

Comment: I guess I understood what you are trying to do now -> updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

Let me see if I understand you correctly, you want to find the element with  the classes 'form-text' 'x-form-field' and 'x-combo-noedit', only if the containing div is a sibling of the label with text "Mailing account"

Way to do this using just xpath:

```
WebElement firstElement = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//label[contains(text(), 'Mailing Account:')]"));
WebElement secondElement = firstElement.findElement(By.xpath("./following-sibling::div[1]//input[@class='form-text x-form-field x-combo-noedit']"));
```

OR as you wrote if you want to match ANY of the classes then the "input" part of your second xpath to this:

```
//input[contains(@class,'form-text') or contains(@class ,'x-form-field') or contains(@class ,'x-combo-noedit')]
```

If you want to combine everything into just one expression, you can use the following xpath:

```
String xpath = "//label[contains(text(), 'Mailing Account:')]/following-sibling::div[1]//input[contains(@class,'form-text') or contains(@class ,'x-form-field') or contains(@class ,'x-combo-noedit')]";
// and then just find the element
driver.findElement(By.xpath(xpath));
```

Comment: sorry, I am not looking for separate finds. I want a single find using a nested query! Something like `//label[match on text]//div[match on class]`

Comment: sorry didn't read the "any" the first time, updated my answer, hope it helps

Comment: Ok, make sense now. I wonder is there a way to combine these two queries into single?

Comment: of course you can combine them, but then it will become hard to read -> I'll update my answer